# R create variable based on presence in data frame

Tags: r, count, cpu-word

new to R and have been struggling with this one. I want to create a new column, that checks if a set of any of words ("foo", "x", "y") exist in column 'text', then write that value in new column.

I have a data frame that looks like this: a->

```
 id     text        time   username
 1     "hello x"     10     "me"
 2     "foo and y"   5      "you"
 3     "nothing"     15     "everyone"
 4     "x,y,foo"     0      "know"
```

The correct output should be:

a2 ->

```
id     text        time   username        keywordtag  
 1     "hello x"     10     "me"          x
 2     "foo and y"   5      "you"         foo,y
 3     "nothing"     15     "everyone"    0 
 4     "x,y,foo"     0      "know"        x,y,foo
```

Any hints on how to do this would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this [a duplicate of your similar question from January 2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34952321/r-extract-and-paste-keyword-matches)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another way using `apply` and `sapply`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(text = c("hello x", "foo and y", "nothing", "x,y,foo"))
terms <- c('foo', 'x', 'y')
df1$keywordtag <- apply(sapply(terms, grepl, df1$text), 1, function(x) paste(terms[x], collapse=','))
df1
#        text keywordtag
# 1   hello x          x
# 2 foo and y      foo,y
# 3   nothing           
# 4   x,y,foo    foo,x,y
```

Answer (score 0):

another thought is the dreaded loop... perhaps not so bad if you pre-allocate?

```
options(stringsAsFactors=F)
df1 <- data.frame(text = c("hello x", "foo and y", "nothing", "x,y,foo"))
newcol <- rep(NA, nrow(df1))
for(i in 1:nrow(df1))
  newcol[i] <- paste( unlist(strsplit(df1$text[i], " "))[ grep("foo|x|y", unlist(strsplit(df1$text[i], " ")))], collapse=", ")
```